# Dynamic binding of event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event handler

```
$(document).on("click","li.folder",function(e){
    alert(e.target);
});
```

where folder is a custom class.

The folders are appended to a ul dynamically.

The problem is this event handler fires every time wherever I click in the entire document even for elements with tags other than **li** and class other than **folder**.

I thought the **li.folder** in the second argument filters out the events?

**HTML**

```html
<ul id="fileList" data-role="listview"></ul>

<li class="node folder ui-li-1line-bigicon1" id="row%id%" label="%name%" uri="%uri|escapeEncies%" fullUri="%fullUri|escapeEncies%">
    <form class="my-ui-checkbox hidden"><input type="checkbox" /></form>
    <img src="images/folder.png" class="ui-li-bigicon" />
    <span class="ui-li-text-main nodename">%name|escape%</span>
</li>
```

I am pushing this li element into the ui (The real code is quite big ).

I know maybe i can use the ui#filelist as my selector but i want to know why the problem arises in this case?

**EDIT:**

@George his fiddle does work fine, but i think my problem is that i have hidden buttons all over my document, they are the ones firing this, but they do not belong to **folder** class

Comment: it should filter out. or else if you have `folder` class assigned just to `li`s then you can just try by binding it as `$(document).on("click",".folder",function(e){`

Comment: which ul you are appending the folder li. ul is static or dynamic ,if it is static  give that name

Comment: can you post your html too??

Comment: You have coded any click for document??

Comment: I'm pretty sure adding a click handler for the whole document is quite resource heavy, can you not apply it to the `ul`?

Comment: Works fine in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8411zxmm/

Comment: The why is because you told it to listen at the document level.  So, every document click is going to pass through all click listeners to see if this is the class/el that i want (.folder)  If not, it breaks the "loop" and moves on the the next element it found.     So, yes, you should use the ul, or the parent div of that ul if the ul doesn't exist at DOM-ready time either.   A good rule is to always try to delegate to the next closest available at ready parent.

Comment: @George your fiddle works fine, but i think my problem might be that i have hidden buttons all around the document, they are the ones firing this, even though they are not folders.